# Guava LoadingCache not working in SpringBoot app?

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava

I have a Guava LoadingCache defined that accepts a search criteria request. The search criteria class properly implements `equals` and `hashCode` and this is verified with a unit test.

The cache works properly and caches search results in unit tests but when running as a SpringBoot app, the cache doesnt work and is calling `load` each time `get(key)` is called.

I would post my code but I've varified through logging and tests that the cache works other than when running as a SpringBoot fat jar.

Is there something I don't know about Spring that would cause this?

EDIT:
Class containing LoadingCache:

```
public class ObjectCache {

private static ObjectCache objectCache = null;
LoadingCache<Key, Object> serviceCache;

private ObjectCache(){
    System.out.println("creating cache");
    serviceCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES)   
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .build(new CacheLoader<Key, Object>() {
                public Object load(Key key) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("uncached request - calling legacy service: " + key.hashCode());
                    return ServiceCaller.callLegacyFindPatient(key);
                }
            });
}

public static ObjectCache getObjectCache(){
    if(_patientCache == null){
        _patientCache = new FindPatientCache();
    }
    return _patientCache;
}

public LoadingCache<Key, Object> getCache(){
    return this.serviceCache;
}
```

}

The cache is used like so: `ObjectCache.getPatientCache().getCache().get(key);`

In unit tests, the cache works and I see the duplicate hashes. When running as a SpringBoot app, the same calls result in the cache calling the legacy webservice each time even though the hashes show as the same.

**EDIT**: Console output when called as SpringBoot app, you can see identical hashes trigger the load.

```
creating cache
uncached request - calling native service for key: 2076189345
uncached request - calling native service for key: 2076189345
```

Comment: *"The cache works properly and caches search results in unit tests but when running as a SpringBoot app, the cache seems to work and is calling load each time get(key) is called."* What is the problem here?

Comment: My guess is that you have many caches, and not just one. But since you post no code...

Comment: @user2004685 - The cache doesn't* work. Edited.

Comment: @JBNizet - I'm logging whenever a cache is created and verified it's not multiple caches. I am going to add the code but with the same code working fine in unit tests, I don't think a problem will be evident.

Comment: please, attach a code snippet, because currently it;s all about guessing

Comment: Code and output attached.

Comment: Does your key implement `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: Getting your `ObjectCache` is not thread-safe, you risk creating multiple instances. Use `synchronized` or static initialization of a holder class if you want deferred creation, or just initialize the singleton on load.

Comment: I will handle the thread safety but if that were the problem in my current testing I'd get the logging showing a second cache creating. This I think is has something To do with Spring ::

Comment: Hi @Half_Duplex
Did you manage to find the answer for this?